# Data type Varchar2 to date format

Tags: oracle, varchar2

I am writing `SQL` code to extract data for effective start date greater than or equal to 24/09/2018 00:00:00. My effective_start_date data type is in `varchar2`. Below is the code I am using:

```
TO_DATE(TRUNC(effective_start_date),'DD/MM/YY') >='24/09/2018 00:00:00')
```

Comment: Hi Lurker, thanks for your response.

Comment: My data contains effective start date column with date format dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00 and data type is varchr2. So when i trying to give condition >=24/09/2018 00:00:00, the result out put bringing all entries.

Comment: Fix the table. This design is broken as is. It's **never** a good idea to store date values as string (varchar) types.

Comment: can you indicate your database- sql server, mysql etc

Comment: **Never** store date or timestamp values in a `varchar` column. As Joel has mentioned you should rather fix your broken database design.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select case
 when  Cast(effective_start_date as dateTime) >= cast('2018/09/24 00:00:00' as dateTime) 
 then 1 --your business
 else 
 0  --your business
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
trunc(to_date( effective_start_date, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS' )) >= to_date('24/09/2018 00:00:00', 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Storing datetime as varchar is very wrong.